# Overloading instance function of a Singleton class

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

Is it the best way to overload an instance function to accept parameters, In the following code snippet i am  passing file name of the log file. Is it good to do like this?

> Logger.GetIntance("Temp.log");
>
> Logger.GetIntance().WriteLog("Program
>   Start");

Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: I don't thing that´s a good idea. I've never seen this approach before. Wouldn't it be better if you had a "SetFileName" function or something?

Answer (score 1):

`getInstance()` is not an instance-method. It's a static method. If the `Logger` is a singleton, then you can't logically have two different methods to obtain the same instance.

If you need to initialize the singleton, then do that in the class itself. It will be initialized in just one place anyway, so it better be inside.

But loggers are rarely singletons, and `Logger.getInstance(..)` usually returns a new instance. So it is fine to overload it.

Comment: Can you please tell me why it i can't have two different methods to obtain the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow design patterns, then I'd suggest you initialize the logger with file name inside the class. If the file name is not known during that time (it changes) then it is questionable whether you need to have a singleton at all.